# Python y tkinter, problema con suma de listbox

Tags: python, vscode

Quiero hacer lo que esta en la imagen, pero no pudo hacer la suma del listbox ,pero no se como hacerlo me eh quedado atrapado, ¿algún consejo?.

La verdad ya no sé qué hacer con el código, he buscado información pero no encuentro lo que busco; quería saber si me podrían dar algún consejo para sumar el poder sumar el listbox para obtener el resultado.

Me he quedado atascado aquí y no puedo terminar, me podrían dar algún consejo para mejorar el código y obtener la suma.

El código lo hizo en vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
ferr = tkinter.Tk()
ferr.title("Ferreteria")
var = tkinter.StringVar
#Titulo y tamaño

titulo = tkinter.Label(ferr, text="Ferretería el tronillo feliz",font=("tamaño" ,30, 'bold'))
titulo.grid(row=0,column=0)
#Funcion para ingresar el producto

productos = tkinter.Label(ferr, text="Ingresar Productos",font= ("tamaño",10))
productos.grid(row=1, column=0)
texto1  = tkinter.Entry(ferr, width =80)
texto1.grid(row=3, column=0)
herramientas = tkinter.Listbox(ferr,width=80)
herramientas.grid(row=4,column=0)

#Funcion para ingresar el dinero

precio = tkinter.Label(ferr, text="Ingresar Precio",font= ("tamaño",10))
precio.grid(row=1, column=1)
dinero  = tkinter.Entry(ferr, width =20)
dinero.grid(row=3, column=1)
precio2 = tkinter.Listbox(ferr,width=20)
precio2.grid(row=4,column=1)

# Creando la funcion de insert

def insert():
    tabla = texto1.get()
    herramientas.insert(tkinter.END,tabla)
    monto = dinero.get()
    precio2.insert(tkinter.END,monto)
    
    
         
#Boton de ingreso de datos
    
button1 = tkinter.Button(ferr, text= "Agregar", padx=12, command=insert )
button1.grid(row=3,column=2)

#Creando el subtototal

def fnsub():
    global numero3
    numero1 = dinero.get()
    numero2 = float(numero1) + float (numero1)
    numero3 = numero2
    subtotal1.insert(0,numero3)

subtotal = tkinter.Checkbutton(ferr,text= "Subtotal:                                             ",onvalue= 1, offvalue=0,command=fnsub)
subtotal.grid(row=6,column=1)
subtotal1 = tkinter.Listbox(ferr,width=10,height=1, )
subtotal1.grid(row=6, column=1)

# Creando la factura

def fnfac():
    global num3
    num2 = float(0.18)
    num3 = float(num2)* float(numero3)
    factura2.insert(tkinter.END,num3)

factura1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(ferr,text= "Factura:                                             ",onvalue= 1, offvalue=0,command=fnfac)
factura1.grid(row= 7 ,column=1) 
factura2 = tkinter.Listbox(ferr,width=10,height=1 )
factura2.grid(row=7, column=1)

#creando el total

def suma():
    suma=float(num3)+float(numero3)
    total2.insert(tkinter.END,suma)
    
total1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(ferr,text= "Total:                                             ",onvalue= 1, offvalue=0,command=suma)
total1.grid(row=8,column=1)
total2 = tkinter.Listbox(ferr,width=10,height=1 )
total2.grid(row=8, column=1)


ferr.mainloop()
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno puedes crear una función para obtener los elementos del listbox, guardarlos en una lista, una vez los tengas hacer la sumatoria con un foreach.

```
def GetTotalItems():
listItems = precio2.get(0, tk.END)
total = 0
for item in listItems:
    total += int(item)
print(total)
```

Ya nomas seria insertar el total en el listbox, aqui no se porque usas listbox para mostrar el total si puedes usar un label o un entry